# IntelliJ Share Project on GitHub

Tags: github, intellij-idea, project, share

When I use IntelliJ to share project on GitHub "Share Project On GitHub" popup appears where I can select GitHub Repository. And when I press Share another popup appears asking me again to select GitHub Account. Why am I being asked to select GitHub Repository twice? I don't understand the difference between these two popups.

When I click on question mark there is no explanation for Share by option on the first popup. Is Share by specifying Username which can then create Repository on some other GitHub Account selected on the second window?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was initially reported in [`IDEA-247272`](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-247272/Duplicate-github-accounts-in-Choose-Github-Account)

> Please:
>
> - navigate to `Version Control` | `GitHub` settings,

- remove duplicating accounts and
- re-add just 1 correct.

That could help prevent the second prompt.